# Correct syntax for "mirror" pie operator in UV Editor as one operator

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

What is the correct way to in the UV editor perform an X or Y mirror as one command for a pie operator?

```
pie.operator("transform.mirror()", text="Mirror").constraint_axis='True, False, False'
```

Based on what I saw in the console:

```
bpy.ops.transform.mirror(constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SPHERE', proportional_size=0.0323492)
```

I struggle to understand the logic because I was able to successfully do this with a different snapping command

```
bpy.ops.uv.snap_cursor(target='SELECTED')
```

has to be written as

```
pie.operator("uv.snap_cursor", text="Snap Cursor to Selected").target='SELECTED'
```

Alternatively I could just define an operator and call the name via a pie button but I feel this makes the script longer than needed

Comment: lose the parentheses and add ones at the end `pie.operator("transform.mirror", text="Mirror").constraint_axis=(True, False, False)`

Comment: Actually I tried this. What happens is that you start the mirror command and have to press x or y for the direction. the constraint definition will be ignored.

Comment: try clicking the leftMouse without specifying the axis and read the executed command in blender you'll see it is not ignored

Comment: My eyes fool me. True without the constraint it goes into asking you. With the data it executes what you define and still enables you to overwrite it via X or Y or press LMB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of the operator can be found [here](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.ops.transform.html?highlight=transform.mirror#bpy.ops.transform.mirror).

`bpy.types.UILayout.operator` returns an `bpy.types.OperatorProperties` object.

So if you need to assign multiple presets, assign it to a local variable first

```
op_props = pie.operator("transform.mirror", text="Mirror")
op_props.constraint_axis = True, False, True
#...
```

When the operator's invoke method is called the operator may use user input to set its properties or run modal, before finally running its execute method.

To skip the invocation you might try:

```
#...
pie.operator_context = "EXEC_DEFAULT"
pie.operator("transform.mirror").constraint_axis = True, False, True

pie.operator_context = "INVOKE_DEFAULT"
#...
```

See [UILayout.operator_context](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=layout.operator#bpy.types.UILayout.operator_context) for the available options